# How can i send a large array to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error when sending an array with a length greater than 250 to MVC controller. It works when array length is less than 250 items.

Client Code

```
function saveVD() {
    var arr = [];
    $.each($("#tablevd tbody tr"), function () {
        arr.push({
                invNo: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html().trim(),
                invDate: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html().trim()
            })
    })
    $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("Absorb","My")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'arr': arr }),
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        })
}
```

Server Code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Absorb(CIVM[] arr)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
public class CIVM
{
    public string invNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime invDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting so we can answer more precisely?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622106/posting-a-large-json-object-to-asp-net-mvc/18622722

Comment: I have got the solution . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below config changes may help you

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622106/posting-a-large-json-object-to-asp-net-mvc/18622722'...